# Validation rule for currency with 2 decimal values

Tags: validation, salesforce

**Valid:** 12.00, 12.10, 12.01, 12.56
**Not Valid:** 12, 12.1, 12.0

NOT(REGEX(TEXT(Price__c), "[0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]?"))

I am writing an validation rule in salesforce for currency field. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Why?

Salesforce will internally respect the "length" and "decimal places" properties selected in the field properties.

If you'll enable debug logging while trying to save you'll realize the value is properly formatted before it enters the validation.

```
Input: 123

21:21:42.149 (149682056)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|NOT(
    CONTAINS(TEXT(decimal__c), '.') &&
    BEGINS(RIGHT(TEXT(decimal__c),3), '.')
)|decimal__c=123.00

21:21:42.149 (149693305)|VALIDATION_FAIL

Input: 50.0111
(...)
decimal__c=50.01
```

If you want to do something with it I think you'll have to present the users a text field and process it with validation and either formula field or some workflow that'd be writing value to the real Currency field.